# Is it possible to perform Method Hiding without using New keyword?

Tags: c#, oop

Today I had an interview where I have been asked

> Is it possible to perform Method Hiding without using New keyword?

As far as I know , it is not possible. So I said that.

Is there any (seriously) tricky / alternate way to perform Method Hiding? I thought of ***Sealed*** once....

Also like ***Explicit Interface***, is there something of that sort...(not sure)

**Edited**

As a last question on this topic, like we can do for explicit interface

```
 Interfacename.Method name
```

Can we do something similar for a derived class like.

```
Class Derived:Base
{ 
  public void Base.SomeMethod(){}
}
```

Comment: You get asked this kind of thing on a job interview? Wow, sounds so specific and theoric! Putting the keyword in or not has the same outcome...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely - if you don't specify *anything*, you still get the same effect as with the `new` modifier, but you get a warning as well.

There's also explicit interface implementation, of course.

In both cases, just casting the target to a different type "unhides" the method:

```
((BaseClass) x).SomeMethod();
((IFoo) x).SomeMethod();
```

Sealing a class has nothing to do with method hiding though - or rather, it prevents any derived classes from hiding a method, by making sure there *are* no derived classes.

Comment: Yes Sir, before looking into your answer, I edited the same and started thinking along the way...thanks Sir.

Comment: As a last question on this topic, like we can do for explicit interface Interfacename.Method name. Can we do something similar for a derived class like. Class Derived:Base{ public void Base.SomeMethod(){}} (:

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: No, that's nothing like that possible. It's not even clear what it would mean or why you'd want to do it.